# AWS - Redirecting a Route53 hosted zone to a URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, redirect, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

[image]I created a hosted zone in Route53.

How can I point it to a url ( Ec2 - which has tomcat app running ) index.html

The Alias option comes disabled for hosted zone.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**First Thing:** You're trying to edit the record with type `NS` i.e name servers, that's why you have an aliases option non-editable there, this record is created by AWS by default, you shouldn't edit them.

Assuming your domain name is `example.com`

If you want your site to be hosted in `example.com` without any subdomain, You should follow the below steps:

- Create Record
- Leave record name as blank
- Choose Record Type `A`
- Place your EC2 instance IP Address in value.

This will work (assuming you own that domain, and mapped nameservers in the domain provider)

Comment: Got it, So in addition to two already existing records NS and SOA (Unless I delete those two, - As I dont know the purpose as they were created when I registered the domain) I have to create new subdomain record:  There are two open issues:  1. The new record expects the subdomain name, which I dont want.  2. Where can I specify the port and rest of URL.  I was able to hit it with subdomain ( See. http://test.logspate.com:8080/ ) But in this case I have to put port number. Secondly I want to just use http://logspate.com, And thirdly, Where can I put rest of url. ( After the PORT part ).